# Automated Test CYPRESS 5.4: Cannot Read Property 'data'

Tags: wordpress, automated-tests, cypress

doing the self-test with cypress on a WP platform when I go to click here:
[image]

with this cypress command:

```
cy.get('#post-3927 > td.title.column-title.has-row-actions.column-primary.page-title > div.row-actions > span.edit > a').click({force:true})
```

the command is successful but when I go to load the next page I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding in

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

in cypress/support/index.js